# Running multiple scripts in sequence in Python

Tags: python, executable

I am running multiple scripts in sequence according to the list `I` and the following executable. However, when one of the script in folder (say, `2`) runs into an error, it terminates instead of moving to folder `3`. Basically I want the executable to move onto the next script if there is an error in the present script. How do I do this?

```
I=[1,2,3]
for i in I: 
    exec(open(rf"C:\5100 nodes\{i}\5100_beta_0.01_50.0_1.0ND_3.py").read())
```

The error encountered while running script in folder `2` is

```
File "<string>", line 618, in <module>

ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a try-except block.

```
I=[1,2,3]
for i in I:
    try: 
        exec(open(rf"C:\5100 nodes\{i}\5100_beta_0.01_50.0_1.0ND_3.py").read())
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
```